# How can I use DropDownListFor() on a dynamic type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, expression-trees, html.dropdownlistfor

I get the following error in the `DropDownListFor()` "**An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation**" because the lambda uses a dynamic type.

How can I set the selected option on the DropDownList without resorting to jQuery?

I would also rather not make a template or custom helper.

**Model**

```
public class Thing : Base {
    public virtual Nullable<int> OptionID { get; set; }
    public virtual Option Option { get; set; }
}
public class Option : Base {
    public virtual ICollection<Thing> Things { get; set; }
}
public class Base {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int Id) {
    return View(new ViewModel(context, new Thing()));
}
```

**View**

```
@model MvcApp7.Models.ViewModel
@{
    var Entity = (dynamic)Model.Entity;
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Entity.OptionID , (System.Web.Mvc.SelectList)Model.Options)
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel {
    public ViewModel(Context context, object entity) {
        this.Entity = entity;
        this.Options = new SelectList(context.Options, "Id", "Name");
    }
    public dynamic Entity { get; set; }
    public SelectList Options { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**: Please excuse me. I forgot that I could specify the selected option in the SelectList itself. I moved the responsibility into the ViewModel and will try to deal with it from there. However, it would still be good to know how to work around this in the View itself in case it was necessary.

I did this in the ViewModel
`this.Options = new SelectList(context.Options, "Id", "Name", this.Entity.OptionID);`
and this in the View
`@Html.DropDownList("OptionID", Model.Options)`

Answer (score 0):

**View**

```
@model MvcApp7.Models.ViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Entity.OptionID , (System.Web.Mvc.SelectList)Model.Options)
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel {
    public ViewModel(Context context, object entity) {
        this.Entity = entity;
        this.Options = new SelectList(context.Options, "Id", "Name");
    }
    public dynamic Entity { get; set; }
    public SelectList Options { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter. This is the first thing I tried and it gives the same error `CS1963: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation` That is why I tried the casting thing (as a guess really).

Comment: Can you use a generic view model with a common interface? Something like `ViewModel<T> where T : IHasOptions`.

Comment: Maybe. I saw that mentioned elsewhere. I have not used interfaces yet as I am only 2-3 months into C# and my totally amateur impression is that they are a pain. Wouldn't that have a similar effect to making the view strongly-typed? I think I am going to attempt to make the ViewModel class more dynamic than it currently is.

Comment: BTW I found a workaround in the meantime and edited my question to include it.